# reusable live click function

Tags: jquery, live, jquery-click-event, die

I have a live click function that is quite long and at one point I'm using `die()` on it. At another point in the code I need to re-live it.

```
$("#id").live("click", function(e) {
    //30+ lines of code
    if([some condition]){
        $("#id").die("click");
    }
});

function foo(){
    $("#id").live("click", function(e) {
        //Exact same code as before.. but I don't want to re-type it.
    });
}
```

I've tried pre-defining the function like so:

```
function clickEvent(e){
    //the code
}

$("#id").live("click", clickEvent(e));
```

but that didn't work at all.

Any help?

Comment: use `$("#id").live("click", 'clickEvent');`

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated, use `.on()` for a start

Comment: @TamilSelvan could you elaborate? How do I pass the `e` variable? I tried `$("#id").live("click", 'clickEvent(e)');` but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use `.on` (`.live` is deprecated) and use the if condition inside that instead of using `.die()`

```
    $("#id").on("click", function(e) {
        //30+ lines of code
        if([some condition]){
          //do nothing
        }
        else{
          //code that should work on click 
        }
    });
```